# How to send a file with space and multiple characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In my folder I have several files that after generated are with titles with spaces and multiple characters. I am successful when the file is just a word like: `music.mp3`, however some files are with titles like: `Music Band - Music Name (New Músic).mp3`

my code attempt:

```
const musicTitle = JSON.stringify(data.title);
client.sendAudio(message.from, './media/' + musicTitle + '.mp3', null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to encode the file name.

```
const musicTitle = encodeURIComponent(data.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace() method and replace blank space characters (or any character like ' - ') for a 'no-space':

```js
let str = 'Music Band - Music Name (New Músic).mp3'

str.replace(' ', '');
str.replace(' - ', '');
```